# How do I get the HTTP Terminal SDK to work with a custom provider?

Tags: typescript

I can hook into the normal HTTP provider like:

```
import { TerminalHttpProvider, SourceType } from '@terminal-packages/sdk';
import Web3 from 'web3';
 
const web3 = new Web3(
  new TerminalHttpProvider({
    host: 'https://yourethnodeurl.io',
    apiKey: 'yourApiKey',
    source: SourceType.Terminal
  })
);
```

Does anyone know how to make it use a custom provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is possible by using the custom provider object property like this:

```
import { TerminalHttpProvider, SourceType } from '@terminal-packages/sdk';
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(
  new TerminalHttpProvider({
    apiKey: 'yourApiKey',
    source: SourceType.Terminal,
    customHttpProvider: new YourCustomHttpProvider()
  })
);
```